# How to receive integration event from RabbitMQ broker using MassTransit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to receive an event from the RabbitMQ broker but something wents wrong, the Consume method of my consumer is never called, although the message is visible on the bus. Here's my IntegrationEvent class:

```
public abstract class IntegrationEvent
{
    protected IntegrationEvent(Guid entityId,
        string eventType)
    {
        EntityId = entityId;
        EventType = eventType;
    }
        
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public Guid EntityId { get; }
    public string EventType { get; }
    public DateTime? PublishedAtUtc { get; set; }
}
```

And the example inheritor:

```
public sealed class UserCreatedIntegrationEvent : IntegrationEvent
{
    public UserCreatedIntegrationEvent(Guid id,
        string login,
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string mailAddress)
            : base(id,
                nameof(UserCreatedIntegrationEvent))
    {
        Login = login;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        MailAddress = mailAddress;
    }

    public string Login { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string MailAddress { get; }
}
```

Publication logic:

```
public async Task PublishAsync(params IntegrationEvent[] events)
{
    var globalPublicationTasks = events
        .Select(@event =>
        {
            @event.PublishedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

            return _publishEndpoint.Publish(@event);
        });

    await Task.WhenAll(globalPublicationTasks);
}
```

Receiver classes and the dependencies registry code:

```
public sealed class IntegrationEventListener : BackgroundService
{
    public IntegrationEventListener(IBusControl busControl,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IOptions<RabbitMQSettings> busConfiguration)
            : base(busControl,
                serviceProvider,
                busConfiguration,
                NullLogger.Instance)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var handler = BusControl
                .ConnectReceiveEndpoint(BusConfiguration.HostName, receiveEndpointConfigurator =>
                {
                    receiveEndpointConfigurator
                        .Consumer<IntegrationEventTransmitter>(ServiceProvider);
                });
            
            await handler.Ready;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public sealed class IntegrationEventTransmitter : IntegrationEventHandler<IntegrationEvent>
{
    public override async Task HandleAsync(IntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public abstract class IntegrationEventHandler<TIntegrationEvent>
    : IIntegrationEventHandler<TIntegrationEvent>,
      IConsumer<TIntegrationEvent>
          where TIntegrationEvent : IntegrationEvent
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TIntegrationEvent> context) =>
        await HandleAsync(context.Message);

    public abstract Task HandleAsync(TIntegrationEvent @event);
}

...
.AddRabbitMQ(configuration,
    ExchangeType.Fanout,
    true)
.AddScoped<IntegrationEventTransmitter>()
.AddHostedService<IntegrationEventListener>();
...

        internal static IServiceCollection RegisterRabbitMQDependencies(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            string exchangeType)
        {
            var rabbitMQSettings = configuration
                .GetSection(RabbitMQSettingsSectionKey)
                .Get<RabbitMQSettings>();

            services
                .AddMassTransit(configurator =>
                {
                    configurator.AddConsumers(typeof(IntegrationEventHandler<IntegrationEvent>).Assembly);
                })
                .AddSingleton(serviceProvider => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configurator =>
                {
                    configurator
                        .Host(rabbitMQSettings.HostName,
                            rabbitMQSettings.VirtualHostName,
                            hostConfigurator =>
                            {
                                hostConfigurator.Username(rabbitMQSettings.UserName);
                                hostConfigurator.Password(rabbitMQSettings.Password);
                            });

                    configurator.ExchangeType = exchangeType;
                }))
                .AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>())
                .AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>())
                .AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>())
                .Configure<RabbitMQSettings>(configuration.GetSection(RabbitMQSettingsSectionKey));

            return services;
        }
```

In the RabbitMQ management panel i can notice that message is being properly published on the bus, the consumer is also connected to the broker but for some reason it does not consume the message. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your configure is so far off the documented approach, I'd suggest getting inline with the [standard configuration](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/), and stop registering all those interfaces yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should not connect a receiving endpoint, as it's completely unnecessary in this case. As Chris mentioned, configuring MassTransit for ASP.NET Core is properly described in the documentation, and it makes total sense to [follow the documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core) to avoid unnecessary complexity.

In your particular case, you don't start the bus, although it's even mentioned in the [Common Mistakes](http://masstransit-project.com/troubleshooting/common-gotchas.html) article as the first thing.

Just do the following:

- Use `AddMassTransit` in `Startup` and configure the receive endpoint normally
- Add the handler directly there, or use a consumer class instead. It does not need to be a background service, MassTransit will call it when it receives a message
- Register the MassTransit host by calling `AddMassTransitHostedService`